# Angularjs : Learning how ngChecked works

Tags: angularjs

I tried modifying the ng-checked example so that clicking on one of the checkboxes would automatically update the other.

Clicking A, then B, then A again, is not doing what I'm expecting.

What part of the documentation should I look at to understand what's happening ?

http://jsfiddle.net/cantcopy/ev62U/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you connect both checkboxes to the same model ?

```
<div ng-app>
  A - Check me to check both: 
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master"><br/>
  B - Check me to check both:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master">
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ev62U/133/

==================================================================================

To explain your fiddle:

`ng-checked` does not update the model, it only updates the view (checkbox), once the expression changes.

Click A: the `master` is changed to `true`, the B checkbox is watching its `ng-checked` value and therefore updates the view to be checked as well.

Click B: the `master2` is changed to `false`, the A checkbox is watching its `ng-checked` value and therefore updates the view to be unchecked as well.

Click A: the `master` is set to `true` and that's not really a change as the value already was `true`, so it does not trigger update of B.